# Chess variant-Is it strategically good?

Tags: strategy, chess-variants

In this chess variant, the number of moves made both chess players are 1 & 2 alternatively. Here is a showing of it.

White        Black

1                   2

2                   1

1                    2

2                    1

1                    2

2                    1

Is this a good chess variation, strategically speaking? Could this lead to new ideas and complexity in the game?

Comment: What happens if a player gives check on first of his two moves?

Comment: The player who has two moves to make gives a check is not counted as a chess move. He/She has another two moves to make.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar what if only legal moves are checks ?

Comment: Continuous legal moves given by the player as checks could be 1,2 or more. The checks are not counted as moves. Once the checks are completed, the player will make a single or two moves depending upon his turn which are not check moves.

Comment: Does chess really *need* more complexity?

Comment: https://www.ichess.net/blog/best-chess-engines/  Can a chess program be designed and developed on this pattern?

Comment: The rules to this game, particularly involving checks, are a bit confusing.  It would be extremely helpful if you could provide an example game that illustrates exactly how the rules work.

Comment: About the check rule: Maybe better phrase it as "If the first move of a 2-move set is a check, the second move is forfeited" or something.

Comment: In any case, I think the game will get a lot more defensive as all pawns and pieces have a hugely increased area of influence and one has to tread very carefully to not lose anything to "hit-and-run raids".

Comment: https://www.ichess.net/blog/best-chess-engines/ A chess program can be designed and developed with this design pattern?

Comment: It would be useful if you explained the rules about checks **clearly** in the question.

Comment: Seems like Marsellais Chess but with alternating moves between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

> Continuous legal moves given by the player as checks could be 1,2 or more. **The checks are not counted as moves.** Once the checks are completed, the player will make a single or two moves depending upon his turn which are not check moves.

If I'm understanding this correctly, this seems very degenerate and an easy win for white after 1. e3.  No matter what black does for their two moves, it white should be able to play either 2. Qf3 & Qxf7+ OR 2. Qh5 & Qxf7+ OR 2. Qg4 & Qxd7+.  Checks don't count as moves, so it is still white's turn.  So, white's queen simply gobbles up black's entire queenside with checks: Qxe7,  Qxd8, Qxc8, Qxb8, Qxa8.  A further continuation (still on white's move) could be Qd8 Qe7 Qf7 Qxf8 Qxg8 Qxh8, gobbling up the entire kingside.  Since queens are so powerful (due to the checks aren't moves rule) and black no longer has one (and is also down massive amounts of material), white should be able to win with minimal effort from here.

Comment: In this chess variation, White & Black has equal chances of winning. When White plays 2 moves, Black plays only 1 move. Next time, White plays 1 move, Black has two moves. So its a equal chance for both. Do you feel the check moves should be considered as 1 or 2? Remember When There is a check by one player, the other player (opponent) responds to it.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the rules.  After white plays 1. e3, suppose black plays 1... a6 and h6.  As I understand them, checks don't count as moves.  Is it legal for white to then play, all in a row before black can do anything: 2. Qf3 Qxf7+ Qxe7+ Qxd7+ Qxd8+ Qxc8+ Qxb8+ Qxa8+ Qd8+ Qe7+ Qxf8+ Qxg8+ Qxh8+ Qxh6? White has only played two non-check moves: namely Qf3 and Qxh6.  Now it is black's turn and black only has a king and four pawns left.

Comment: No. To a check, opponent will respond to it. There cannot be multiple checks at once. A check given by a player will be responded by the opponent immediately.

Comment: Ah.  The response rule was not clear....

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar what makes you think both players have equal chances of winning under your ruleset?

Comment: Thanks David. Both players play 1 & 2 moves alternatively. When White starts with 1 move, Black plays with 2 moves and then next time White gets 2 moves, Black gets 1 move. So i feel there is a even chance for both players. Since White starts the game, i have given him one move and not 2 moves as this may give a edge to White. This is to be traced.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a complex game that involves strategies similar to ordinary chess and yet is humanly playable, see [this post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/29581/9192) where I explain a couple of meta-heuristics in creating very complex chess variants. But a very simple 2-move variant goes as follows:

1. On a player's turn, he/she can make up to 2 moves without a capture or make a single capture, but check ends the turn.
2. To balance the game, White can only make 1 move on the first turn.
3. The player must not be in check after each move even halfway through the turn.

You can do the same to other chess-like games such as Chinese chess, and the resulting games can be really interesting, much more than ordinary chess is!