# If there was a perfect play from both sides, but each player was allowed to do 2 moves every time, would white win?

Tags: chess-variants, solving

Imagine a game where players are allowed 2 moves instead of one. If there were perfect play from both sides, would White win?

Comment: What happens if the first of those two moves is a check?

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/30531/chess-variant-is-it-strategically-good

Comment: name of the variation is called Marseillais Chess.

Comment: @wimi In Marseillais chess, their turn ends

Comment: I'm going to state something basic you've probably heard of.  Black has no winning strategy.  For if Black did a Knight moving first to f3, then g2 for white would force Black to move with no change in position.  Thus the colors would reverse.  So then White would then simultaneously have a winning strategy with the color swap, and also not have one.  This is a contradiction.  Thus Black can't have a winning strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This chess variant you are talking about is Marsellais Chess. I infer that you mean that White has two moves to start with. If this was so, White would have an advantage(a refined version of this variant gives White only 1 move on the first move to null the opening advantage). So White would probably win. However, this is not certain, as we have not written a sufficiently strong engine for this yet.

Comment: *"we have not written a sufficiently strong engine for this yet"* - do you have a reference to back that up? I.e. are there "Marsellais chess engines", if so, what is the win rate of white vs black pieces, when the strongest known engines play? - or are these just your opinions? To me, it is not obvious how much a *balanced* (or more interestingly, *unbalanced*) double-move chess is harder (or not) to solve, compared to ordinary chess. (E.g. unbalanced triple-move chess is a forced win for white on the second move.)